# Is there a WWDC session video that talks about ALAsset and ALAssetLibrary?

Tags: ios, alassetslibrary, alasset, wwdc

I am searching through the titles of the videos in the WWDC app and want to watch a video that shows how the AssetLibrary framework works. How to retrieve assets. There is sample code but I can't find a video.

Someone maybe remembers which session contained information about this framework?

Answer (score 1):

Searching [asciiwwdc](http://asciiwwdc.com): "Searchable full-text transcripts of WWDC-2013 sessions", no session is found.

Comment: No luck: http://asciiwwdc.com/search?q=ALAssetLibrary

Comment: Btw, ASCIWWDC is only WWDC2013. AssetLibrary is an old framework.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that all the videos of the WWDC are available in the URL below(change the last number if you want to jump to a specific year).
https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2013/
  The video you want to find might be Session 421 of WWDC 2010.